# Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.Title) Validate Meta Don't Work

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

When use ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor, it can't reader validate meta info in HTML tag.

```
<textarea rows="2" name="Title" maxlength="100" id="Title" cols="20" 
    class="textbox inp-widx6 tit-2">
    50% OFF Andrew Christian Olympic Deep V Tee, now only £16.34
</textarea>
```

If use Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Title) will reader below content.

```
<input type="text" 
    value="50% OFF Andrew Christian Olympic Deep V Tee, now only £16.34" 
    name="Title" maxlength="100" id="Title" 
    data-val-required="Product title is required." 
    data-val-length-min="50" data-val-length-max="100" 
    data-val-length="The Title must be at least 50 characters &amp;amp;  
    no more than 100 characters." data-val="true" class="textbox inp-widx6 tit-2" />
```

Comment: When the ViewModel object's attribute name is when Title,Uses the TextAreaFor<T> method,is unable to make the DataAnnotations.

Comment: Isn't that because MVC uses `data-val-length-max` instead of `maxlength`? The validation attributes are based on the property attributes in your model. When you use client-side validation it will work out of the box using `TextAreaFor`

Comment: could you post your model class? did you write dataannotation attributes to check maxlength..

Comment: Just reconfirm you have following all steps mentioned steps required. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422573/Model-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 0):

Just reconfirm you have following all steps mentioned steps.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422573/Model-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC